# Is there anything wrong with EER diagram?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, erd

I made the first EER-diagram and I've no one to ask how it looks, and since I don't want to fall face down in the mud, I'd like to ask your advice. What does it look like?

1. I am not sure about the relationship between `Team` and `Match` -tables. Can this be done in this way or should I create a separate bridge table between them?
2. What is the best way to find out which `Teams` are participating in the `Competition`? Should I just use `Join` to combine `Competition`, `Event` and `Match` -tables together, or simply to put the relationship between `Team` and `Competition` -tables? The last one requires `Many-To-Many` relationship and I thought I need to make an another bridge table, which isn't a good idea. Or is it?

[image: EER-diagram, CSGO-DB]